# How to handle CORS issues with two Amazon S3 buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, frontend, postmessage

I am using Amazon S3 + Route53 + third-party open API to do exercises.
I created a bucket A to store the front-end static files and redirected by Route53. The purpose is to have the protection of https, but I found that after third-party API authorization, the same I need to redirect and return the url with the token. In this way, there will be two redirections and the token cannot be obtained. This makes me have to create a bucket B specifically to obtain the url of the token.

But when I used postMessage on the source of bucket A to get the window.open data of the source of bucket B, it happened, Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://xxxx" from accessing a cross-origin frame ERROR

my configuration is like this

Bucket A obtains the authorized redirect URL:

```
https://xxxx.s3.amazonaws.com
```

bucket B CORS config:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
        ],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```

which side of my configuration is causing the problem? Or is there any other way to achieve what I want

Thank you

Comment: What do the buckets have to do with redirect urls and authorization? Maybe you need OPTIONS as well.

Comment: @luk2302 My original idea was to be redirected to the home page deployed in Bucket A after obtaining authorization, for example: https://bucket-a/#access_token=xxx
The problem now is that when the url domin is https://bucket-a, it will be automatically redirected to https://bucket-a/login by Route53, resulting in the inability to obtain the token

Comment: Thank you for saying that OPTIONS is for Storage policy? Or is it for Cross-origin resource sharing?